# Xcode - Localizable.strings working only in English

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I'm trying to get my localizable.strings working properly, but I can't figure out how. My storyboard is localizable too, and works: all buttons and view controllers are shown rightly, in both languages.

But my NSLocalizedStrings loaded programmatically just appears in english. I checked my Localizable.strings, that have 2 languages: English and Brazilian-Portuguese (pt-BR), and I haven't found any problem.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change your device language to Brazilian-Portuguese and then check. It may be works.

Comment: Check your localizable string and Choose Correct language on Device also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this to check if you use the right Language and Region:

```
NSLog(@"Language: %@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Region: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode]);
```

And if you just change the region in the Device-Settings, you have to close and restart your App!

**EDIT**: I think your actual problem is, you use "Brazilian-Portuguese" as Localization, you have to use "Portuguese".

**UPDATE**: In Xcode you can chose between many localizations, but the only options, that take effect in `NSLocalizedString()`, etc. are the Languages you can select on your iPhone in Settings->General->International->Language

Here the complete list at the moment:

> • Arabic • Catalan • Chinese (Simplified) • Chinese (Traditional) •
>   Croatian • Czech • Danish • Dutch • English (U.S.) • English (UK) •
>   Finnish • French • German • Greek • Hebrew • Hungarian • Indonesian •
>   Italian • Japanese • Korean • Malay • Norwegian • Polish • Portuguese
>   • Portuguese (Portugal) • Romanian • Russian • Slovak • Spanish •
>   Swedish • Thai • Turkish • Ukrainian • Vietnamese

Comment: Thanks! I was not finding the option "Portuguese", only with the regions, BR (Brazil) or PT (Portugal). The option appeared when I deleted the existing location. Everything is working properly now, with the locations "English" and "Portuguese".

Comment: I can confirm that although 'pt-BR' is presented as an option when adding a localization to your project, it doesn't actually work on iOS unless you use 'pt' instead!

Answer (score 0):

Just updating @xapslock answer to Swift.

```
    NSLog("Language: " + NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations[0]);
    NSLog("Region: " + (NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String));
```